# Converting a phasor calculation to a complex number in python math

Tags: python, math

I have a problem,
((120)Cos(ArcCos(Rationalize(0.85)))+ (120)Sin(ArcCos(Rationalize(0.85)))I)
this is works on calculator and I want to do it Python.

```
import math
loadValue = 120
powerFactorLag = 0.85

elma = (loadValue)*math.cos(math.acos(math.acos(math.radians(powerFactorLag)))) + (loadValue)*math.sin(math.acos(math.radians(powerFactorLag)))
print(elma)
```

this is my python code and it didn't work what is the problem I didn't understand.

Comment: What is the expected output for that input?

Comment: I expect with the same result with the calculator, when I give these two inputs as values it didn't calculate right

Comment: Yes -- but what *is* that result? You gave numerical inputs, but what is the expected numerical output? What is the actual number that you expect for those inputs?

Comment: for the codes above it gives an error math domain error, i tried the code below it gives 3.56040637393082 output and it is not right

Comment: the answer must be 120+63.213i

Comment: 120 ∠cos^-1(0.85=

Comment: The `120` can't be right since `cos(acos(0.85))` isn't 1. I think you mean `102`

Comment: "120 ∠cos^-1(0.85="  <- @Tuğrul Yıldırım what does this mean? I can't parse it. Can you put that statement into words?

Answer (score 2):

`math.cos(math.radians(powerFactorLag))` makes no sense here. The input to `acos` is a number between -1 and 1. It isn't an angle which needs to be converted from degrees to radians. It isn't an angle at all. The `Rationalize` in the original calculator equation isn't really needed. Maybe when doing such things by hand it might make sense to rationalize an expression before taking its arccos, but when using a calculator it is pointless.

To get a complex number from the two parts, use the function `complex()`:

```
elma = complex((loadValue)*math.cos(math.acos(powerFactorLag)), (loadValue)*math.sin(math.acos(powerFactorLag)))
```

With this, `print(elma))` yields `(102+63.21392251711643j)`

See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/complex-numbers-in-python) for more about using complex numbers in Python.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, but the output wasn't right 120 ∠cos^-1(0.85= this is the question for calc and the result must be 120+63.213i so i fixed the code as you said but didn't works, thanks again btw

Comment: `cmath.rect(loadValue, math.acos(powerFactorLag))` would also work, a bit more concisely. @Tuğrul Yıldırım: Are you _sure_ about that output?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point. I was trying to follow OP's calculator computation as literally as possible, but it is probably better if they just use `cmath` directly when dealing with complex numbers.